# rename Folder in Origin

Tags: git, directory, rename

I have a git repository with a `Components` folder. This folder got renamed to `components` but since the folder is already inside the repository it won't get renamed at the origin reposotory.

How do I rename a folder in the origin repository?

Comment: You mean the remote repository? Just commit the change, i.e. `git mv Components components`, then `git commit` and push the change to the remote repository.

Comment: Be careful if you're on Windows though, since Windows treats file and folder names as case-insensitive, while Unix is case-sensitive.  Not sure what will happen in the Windows case.

Comment: @Cupcake on windows you will get unhappy with case changes, just as with permission changes and files that only differ in casing. on linux it should be a no-brainer (a simple remove + add with new name). op did not tell us what system he uses, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
git mv <old name> <new name>
git commit "Componetens -> components"
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already renamed your folder, without telling git (through a proper `git mv`), you can

```
git delete Components
git add components
git commit -m "rename Components folder to components"
git push
```

The trap is to *add* to the index a second folder "`components`", which a case insensitive OS like Windows would have a hard time displaying, since it wouldn't be able to check out both "`Components`" and "`components`".